# Django Channels, instantiating a new Consumer on the fly, not linked to a Websocket or other protocol?

Tags: django, django-channels

I am building off the [Django Channels Tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html), trying to add a "Chat Manager" consumer to the tutorial's simple chat app. It would function as a simple chatbot, maybe sending a random message in the chatroom every ten seconds, for example. 
The idea is that this ChatManagerConsumer would be created once when a new chat room is made, and only *one* ManagerConsumer exists for the lifespan of the whole chatroom, even as individual users/WebsocketConsumers come and go from the room.

I'm not clear on how to go about doing this.

Background workers would not work, since it looks like you can't programmatically create multiple instances of a background worker; only one can be spawned from the command line. Instead, I would like to have one Consumer instance running per each chat room.

The documentation says "consumers are long-running" and "a chatbot protocol would keep one scope open for the entirety of a user’s conversation with the bot" but doesn't really explain how to open up a consumer for this hypothetical chatbot protocol.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If it is a bot that only responds when a user sends a message, then you don't need a separate background worker as the user's message should trigger to bot to respond. However, if you need to periodically write a message in the chat without being triggered by a user's message then you can run a worker as explained here https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worker.html or use a dedicated cron worker like celery beat

Comment: @Ken4scholars I would prefer to write periodically without being triggered (in the long term, this will be used for a web game, the chat thing is just for practice/testing). However, for Background Workers, it sounds like I can only have one instance for the whole server? Instead, would it be possible to create one "worker" instance per each chatroom? For example, if one of the users gives the chatbot a custom name, that property should only apply to that room's bot, not globally to ALL the bots.

Comment: I realize this could be done manually by having one background worker keep track of the state of all the chatrooms, and send messages out to all of them, acting as though the one worker represents many individual chatbots. But I feel like there must be a more elegant way to accomplish this via Consumers?

Comment: The process running in the background shouldn't in any way be constrained to the bot. You can, of course, decide to create a thread for each game but that is waste of resources and after a few chats, you will have too many threads(or even processes if you decide to) running that will negatively impact the performance of your application. You can have a class of bots that is instantiated each time for chat but run on a single background worker. The bot isn't a consumer on it's own so I don't know what why you feel you should solve the issue using a consumer

Comment: I see, so the idea is to create one background worker that runs all the chatbots globally, then instantiate custom classes for each individual bot instance? And the background worker dispatches messages from the users/Websockets out to the bot instances? That works. That's what I was getting at in the previous comment, I just figured since the Channels documentation is so focused around Consumers, that's the "preferred" approach

Comment: Yes, you got the idea. Of course, you can always scale up the number of background workers if need be, depending on your server infrastructure but my point that there shouldn't be a sort of bot - worker mapping as they should be separate concepts.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, appreciate it :)

Comment: @Ken4scholars Forgot to say, if you'd like, you can put your comments as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Sure, I have pieced two of the comments to make an answer. You can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a bot that only responds when a user sends a message, then you don't need a separate background worker as the user's message should trigger to bot to respond. However, if you need to periodically write a message in the chat without being triggered by a user's message then you can run a worker as explained here channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worker.html or use a dedicated cron worker like celery beat.

The process running in the background shouldn't in any way be constrained to the bot. You can, of course, decide to create a thread for each game but that is waste of resources and after a few chats, you will have too many threads(or even processes if you decide to) running that will negatively impact the performance of your application. You can have a class of bots that is instantiated each time for chat but run on a single background worker. The bot isn't a consumer on it's own so I don't know what why you feel you should solve the issue using a consumer